# Opengl video texture

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm developing an opengl application in C++ on Windows using Visual Studio 10. Currently I use a static texture on a cube but I would like to integrate a video texture.

Do you know which library I can use to open and decrypt video ?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at ffmpeg/libavformat/libavcodec or gstreamer. Threy're pretty straigtforward to use. You should use `glTexSubImage2D` for updating the texture date (using this doesn't do a full texture reinitialization).

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is a good library for this. Have a look here

http://blog.damiles.com/?p=9

and here

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/videotexture.aspx

Comment: This applies to a live video stream coming from a camera or such, though. Not sure that this is what the OP is referring to.