# 3D cube with video on each side in Qt

Tags: qt

I've got a project where I need to be able to display video on all six sides side of a cube that moves and rotates in three dimensions, using Qt. I know the question is vague, but I'm completely new to graphics, so a high-level description of which classes I should look and how they should link together would be a lot of help.  Should I use GLRenderer or the ordinary one?  Is Qt even the right tool for the job?

Comment: opengl is more fitted for the rendering

Comment: Do you have any specific video decoder? If so, look at its documentation to see how to render a video frame to a texture, and then map that texture to one of the sides of the cube. Repeat the process for every side of the cube. Using OpenGL, of course.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do, is use  [QtOpenGL](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/opengl-pbuffers-cube-cpp.html) to render the cube. Then you use [video texturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236785/opengl-video-texture).